# Prove that two linear transformations are equal

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $S,T: V \rightarrow W$ linear transformations and $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ a basis for $V$. It is given that $$\forall i : T(v_i) = S(v_i)$$
Prove that T = S

My approach is assuming $B$ is a basis for $W$ and showing that $[T]^V_B = [S]^V_B$, But I can't explain the logic even if it's true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: You need to show that $S(v) = T(v)$ for all vectors $v\in V$. Write $v = a_1v_1 + \dots+ a_n v_n$, where $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$ are scalars and use linearity of $S$ and $T$.

Comment: Thanks! can you also explain why the approach i suggested is less suitable/wrong?

Comment: What does $[T]^V_B$ mean? (I just don't understand it, and it doesn't mean that it's wrong or less suitable – in maths usually there are many ways of proving a result).

Comment: I forgot to add that i assumed $B$ is a basis in $W$. so $[T]^V_B$ is a representing matrix from $V$ to $B$

Comment: This is a great idea. Note that you need a lemma – if two linear transformations have the same matrices in some basis, then they are equal. Also, if $W$ is infinite dimensional, then $[T]^V_B$ is an infinite matrix (what is conceptually more difficult than the proof above).